# Caracter ' dentro de una cadena de caracteres

Tags: oracle, sintaxis

estoy armando un CASE en oracle pero no logro dar con el resultado correcto.

Ejemplo:

```
CASE
WHEN COLLECTION_ZONE = 'Rancagua' THEN 'REGION DE O'HIGGINS'
ELSE NULL
END AS REGION
```

En la parte de REGION DE O'HIGGINS ese ' corta la cadena hasta O' y HIGGINS no lo considera...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se usan dos single quote para que se entienda como single quote en un string, por lo que veo en internet

```
WHEN COLLECTION_ZONE = 'Rancagua' THEN 'REGION DE O''HIGGINS'
ELSE NULL
END AS REGION
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315340/pl-sql-how-to-escape-single-quote-in-a-string/11315369